# Snappy ubuntu core on BeagleBone Black?

Tags: nodejs, ubuntu-core, beagleboard, snap

What is the best way to develop Snappy applications for Beagle bone black due to snapcraft cross building problem. I can run my Snappy nodejs web in kvm but service is failing on BeagleBone Black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what version of Ubuntu Core you're using, so I'll assume 15.04. In that case, consider an [arm lxc container](https://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/03/ever-wanted-an-armel-or-armhf-container-on-an-x86-machine-its-now-possible-with-lxc-in-ubuntu-precise/) (or just normal qemu). However, if you're willing to give 16.04 a shot, flash [this bbb image](http://people.canonical.com/~mvo/all-snaps/bbb-all-snap.img.xz), SSH onto the device, and run

```
$ sudo snappy enable-classic
```

That will download some stuff, and when it's done, you can run

```
$ snappy shell classic
```

Now you're in the Classic Dimension. You can install and run snapcraft from here!

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install snapcraft
$ cd my/snap/src/
$ snapcraft
```

That will create a snap for the right architecture.

Comment: Thank you...I know for classic mode but i couldnt find 16.04 image...

Comment: Kyle: I did add launchpad.net -> snap packages built-in support. Feel free to review my edit so that it's public :)

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. I only got one more question if anyone of you knows. How to install bonescript (I hope you know what it is).  I put bonescript as a node-package in snapcraft.yaml not in package.json because it is said to install globally. Many errors are thrown and I just want to know if anyone had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another option once you get your snap working on a vm or a board you can build for from your laptop, is to use https://launchpad.net snap built-in support. Push a branch to it, and you will have a **create snap** option, then select your Ubuntu Core series and you will get snaps built from any desired architectures!

Comment: Note that currently internet access (at least non-archive access) is disabled from the Launchpad snap builders, so this will only work if the Snapcraft recipe doesn't require that. They're working on adding that support (a week or two out, it seems).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options there:

- Get access to a server running Ubuntu on ARM and use snapcraft on that device
- Install Ubuntu Mate on a Raspberry Pi and use snapcraft on that device (most popular option)
- Use Qemu (this might need a bit of poking around)